# How can I upload image for product using MEAN stack (Angular2)?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement the creation of product on my MEAN app. I have created a Mongoose schema and connection to the database is working, all fields on frontend also work and the product gets inserted into the database.

Now I want to add an image to the product but can't find an answer here for something like that. I know there are a lot of questions like this one (example: [Angular2 ExpressJs - File upload to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761204/angular2-expressjs-file-upload-to-the-server)), but the answers are for image upload only and I don't know how to implement it on my project. Can someone help?

There are too many lines of code to put here and I think it would be hard to read, so here is a link to GitHub: https://github.com/Janchey/groovy.git

Comment: are you looking for something like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)?

Comment: "but the answers are for image upload only" I may be misunderstanding your question.  Isn't an image upload what you are looking for?

Comment: @SibaprasadMaiti Yea something like multer.

Comment: @Pace The problem is that I don't know how to implement it in my project. Schemas are only for image and in mine are a title, artist, writer, image etc. Not sure if I need function only for image upload, or can some code be added in already created function for product saving...?

Comment: Both methods will work.  I would only bother with a multipart request if you needed things to be transnational or atomic in some way.  A lot of sites these days seem to first have you upload your images and then post your request after they have uploaded.  You might get a preview or be able to add comments or tag people in between.